# How to perform a double click using phpunit_selenium2 extension?

Tags: php, testing, selenium, phpunit, selenium-webdriver

The question is specifically to the phpunit_selenium2.

Comment: @alex: it doesn't work :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So the true opensource way: there is no such a feature? Clone a repo, implement a feature, create pull request, ?????, PROFIT!!!!1

https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit-selenium/pull/212

Now `phpunit_selenium2` supports double click. You can use it like:

```
$this->moveto($element);
$this->doubleclick();
```

[Correspondent example from the tests](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit-selenium/commit/adc70ed6ab7a5bbbdc1eedef39811262c49ce69f#L1R253)